# Blank area on second page while print using NgxPrinterService in angular 13

Tags: angular, printing, angular-material

We are using NgxPrinterService serivce in angular 13 below is the package name

"ngx-printer": "^1.1.0",

When we try to print every second page showing blank area at the top of the page,

[image]

`this._printerService.printHTMLElement(this.receipt.nativeElement);`

where _printerService is NgxPrinterService from ngx-printer package

We have tried multuple @page and @print option like page break css style but did not help

` @media print
{

```
   .hidden-print{
    display: none;
   }

 * {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         font-family: "Calibri", "Calibri", monospace;
         font-size: 14px;
         page-break-after: avoid;
         page-break-before: avoid;             
  }
```

}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of code reviews, I saw the problem with table tr and td code, which causing the problem for this issue. Tried to solve this issue in the table but was unable to fix it, redesigned the same page with the bootstrap row and column, and the issue was resolved.